# How to get a concrete isomorphism (renaming) in the igraph R package while searching for isomorphic subgraphs?

Tags: r, igraph, subgraph, isomorphism

I have two undirected graphs.

```
require (igraph)

gsmall <- graph(c(1,3,5,8,3,5), directed = F)

gbig <- graph(c(3, 5, 3, 10, 4, 5, 4, 10, 5, 7, 5, 8, 5, 9, 7, 10, 8, 10, 9, 10), directed = F)
```

Now I want to know if `gbig` contains a subgraph which is isomorphic to `gsmall`. Or to put it precise I want one specific mapping (if it exists).

In the `igraph` R-package this can be done with the `subgraph_isomorphisms` function. The problem is that this function gives me all isomorphisms which is expensive already in this small example.

So I tried `graph.subisomorphic.lad(gsmall, gbig, all.maps =F)` which gives me

```
$iso
[1] TRUE

$map
[1]  3  1 10  6  9  8  4  5

$maps
NULL
```

as a result. Supposedly `$map` contains the information I need. But I don't know how to use these numbers to generate a renaming of nodes from `gsmall` such that the renamed version of `gsmall` is actually a subgraph of `gbig`. I have the same translation problem with the output of `subgraph_isomorphisms` which according to the help returns a 'list of vertex sequences, corresponding to all mappings from the first graph to the second' which I don't understand.

Can anyone tell me how to get that renaming I want? If I am right with the assumption that the `$map` entry of the result of `graph.subisomorphic.lad(gsmall, gbig, all.maps =F)` contains what I need how can I get that renaming from that point on? If not how to achieve it in another way?

Thanks in advance.